# How to get a resource throug Class?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to using kotlin, and I'm trying to get a resource string in a class.

**Code**

```
fun validateFields(storeBinding: FragmentEditStoreBinding): Boolean {
    var validate = true
    if (storeBinding.etName.text.toString().trim() == "") {
        storeBinding.tilPhotoUrl.error = R.string.helper_required
        validate = false
    }
    return validate
}
```

But it doesn't work because it returns an Integer.

[image]

How can I get the string?

Comment: It doesn't work, because in that class, I haven't got a context. and when I try to use ```getString()```, I need to import it, but of the options, none is valid. It class is a Utils class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the string from resources using Binding.

```
storeBinding.root.context.resources.getString(R.string.helper_required)
```